# EC2 - outbound request limit

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy

We are running our docker containers on ECS with EC2 having 2CPU and 4GB RAM.

The problem that we have encountered is that we are apparently hiting the limit of the EC2 instance for outbound requests.

We have gateway-like service, which is proxying requests.

If we have 1 container with 1CPU for our Node.js project on the whole EC2 instance, we get to about 250RPS (requests per second) and CPU can get up to 80% - which is fine.

However if we run 2 containers on one EC2 machine, each with 1 CPU the RPS does not change, the overall CPU load remains the same (which means only 40% usage for each container) - basically these 2 containers can proxy the same amount of requests and they have enough RAM and CPU to do more.

We have also tried to loadtest our /version endpoint, which is not proxying anything and everything was working as expected - we hit the CPU limit, the autoscaling started, both containers used 100% of whole EC2 instance... So the limit is definitely not in the client->cloudfront->ALB->our gateway containers. Also the limit is not in our Node.js code as two containers on one EC2 instance can proxy same amount of requests as just one container on that EC2 instance.

I did not find anything about outbound EC2 limit like maximum open connections (sockets)... The network bandwidth is actually quite low too - it is 250 RPS for each EC2 instance, the body contains only 50letters (simple JSON), so it should be only few kilobytes for each EC2 instance.

PS: we are using http-proxy library
PS2: We cannot use Fargate yet as it is only available on us-east now and we have deployments across the world

---

Update: Network is using 7Mb/sec (so with 250 RPS it looks like 4kB/request)

Comment: There are very few artificial limits in EC2... but there is a 1024 pps limit per instance on the recursive DNS resolver provided by the network.  I would hope you aren't doing one or more DNS lookups for each request, but if you are, then that seems like a candidate. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Good post actually, we already hit DNS problems with alpine version of docker as it was not caching the DNS and something like you are described happened. However we got proper error message about DNS resolution and the fix was quite easy. To be sure that this is not the problem, we are now testing against external IP address